# LAMP Server и HLS

Tags: html, apache2, видео, streaming, hls

Установил LAMP сервер на VDS с ОС Debian9 на борту, Установил FFMPEG, разбил при помощи FFMPEg файл на сегменты и создал m3u8 плейлист, если скармливать прямую ссылку на плейлист плееру VLC то он идеально воспроизводит файл, а если прописать создать простую html страницу с тегом video, то firefox при открытии страницы отображает интерфейс плеера, но видео не загружает. Mime типы для Apache прописал и в файле `/etc/apache2/mods-available/mime.conf`  и в `.htaccess`.

Mime типы указал так:
`AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8
 AddType video/MP2T .ts`

Код плеера на странице:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>video</title>
 </head>
  <body>
   <video width="352" height="198" controls>
    <source src="https://185.231.153.64/video/playlist.m3u8" 
    type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video>  
 </body>
</html>
```

[Прямая ссылка на плейлист](https://185.231.153.64/video/playlist.m3u8)

[Ссылка на страницу с плеером](https://185.231.153.64/video)

Comment: У вас не верно настроен сертификат для https

Comment: Да я это знаю, он самоподписан в этом и ошибка, после того как полностью разберусь с Сервером куплю нормальный сертификат